# How to add text conditional on numerical ranges in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I'm using Google Sheets and I want to display certain text based on the numerical value of another cell. I am a teacher trying to create an assignment where students have to find the best zombie apocalypse location, and they have to tally total zombie attacks through the first 4 days.

Based on each city's total attacks through 4 days, I want the next cell in the row to display 1 of 4 "City Statuses."

- 0-19 attacks should say "Low Risk,"
- 20-49 is "Medium Risk," 50-99 "High Risk" and
- 100+ attacks is "Evacuate Immediately".

I'm imagining a function that is basically like

```
if G2 < 20, write text "Low Risk";
if G2 > 19 & G2 < 50, write text "Medium Risk";
if G2 > 49 & G2 <100, write text "High Risk"; 
if G2 > 99, write text "Evacuate Immediately".
```

But I'm a newbie to any functions beyond the very basic and don't know how to put together the formula I need to do this.

I've gotten the conditional formatting down, but as far as I can tell that just changes colors. I want to display one of four possible strings of text based on a range of the numerical value of another cell.

Answer (score 1):

#### IFS

You could use nested `IF` functions but they are hard to follow visually and your use case lends itself well to using the `IFS` function.  `IFS` is designed to evaluate multiple conditions and return the value associated with the first true condition.

I posted the formulas below in a demo [Google Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2Xy_2FZxIC6ToKPUHJEBhV-llg9KMSBgWNa0QB0m_A#gid=2100307022)

```
  # Basic Format
  
  =IFS(condition1, value1, [condition2, …], [value2, …])
  
  # where 'x' is a cell reference
  
=IFS( x<20, "Low Risk",
      x<50, "Medium Risk",
      x<100, "High Risk",
      x>99, "Evacuate Immediately" )
```

---

#### Impact of Invalid Source Data

The mathematical comparison operators `<` `>` behave unexpectedly when numbers are compared to either text or NULL values.

```
  # where cell at ref 'x' has value "this" 
  # where cell at ref 'y' has NULL value

  =x<2         =y<2
  ="this"<2    =""<2
  =FALSE       =TRUE

  =x>2         =y>2
  ="this">2    ="">2
  =TRUE        =FALSE
```

This can be avoided using only numbers in the data but optionally the formula can test for these values and manage.

```
  # where cell at ref 'x' has value "this" 
  # where cell at ref 'y' has NULL value

  # Test for text value
 
  =ISTEXT(x)       =ISTEXT(y)
  =ISTEXT("this")  =ISTEXT("")
  =TRUE            =FALSE
 
  # Test for NULL value
 
  =x=""       =y=""
  ="this"=""  =""=""
  =FALSE      =TRUE

=IFS( OR(ISTEXT(x), x=""), "", 
      x<20, "Low Risk",
      x<50, "Medium Risk",
      x<100, "High Risk",
      x>99, "Evacuate Immediately" )
```

**Negative Values**
Also note that the formula will return "Low Risk" for negative values, which presumably are an indication of an error.  If different behavior is preferred a `x<0` check can be added at the beginning of the function.

```
=IFS( OR(ISTEXT(x), x="", x<0), "", 
      x<20, "Low Risk",
      x<50, "Medium Risk",
      x<100, "High Risk",
      x>99, "Evacuate Immediately" )
```

**Demo Sheet**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2Xy_2FZxIC6ToKPUHJEBhV-llg9KMSBgWNa0QB0m_A#gid=2100307022